# windows store app page blank when navigating to it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, navigation, windows-store-apps

I have 3 pages in my application.

First page: 5 `Button`s, each navigates to different page (currently, only the first button works).

Second page: `Back Button` and `ListView`, the `ListViewItems` are `UserControlItems` with `Button`, `Image` and `TextBlock`. When you click on the `Button` (of the `UserControlItem`) it Navigates to the third page, which is Media Player Page with alot of controls.

Third page: Media Player page with alot of controls such as `MediaElement`, `Slider`, `Button`s and more

When I navigate from **Third Page** to **Second Page** using the `Back Button`, **sometimes** the screen stays black (the color of the theme) and `sometimes` it loads too much time. In addition, the `ListView` has visible vertical `scrollbar` (always) which is not shown unless you move your mouse on the `ListView`.

How to fix these problems?

**EDIT 1:**
[link to my project](https://mega.co.nz/#!qNdyUDzL!MXD2o30cvez_KA-HJpKtcQkWasIqI3Da4pnJZCkQVmg) - put some .wmv/.mp3/.mp4 files in the Videos Library folder.

**EDIT 2:**
I investigated the black page issue abit more and I found that the `MediaElement` is the cause.
The `MediaElement` stores the stream and it slows the computer.

In order to resolve to problem, when you click on the `GoBack Button`, it first set the source of the `MediaElement` to null, and only when the `MediaElementState` == Closed, I go back - seems to solve my problem (since I applied the solution I didnt experience more black screens).

About the scrollbar - I think I'll be able to solve it if I simulate `MouseOver` over the `ListView` - no idea how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Ill List out the issue one by one.

List View Scroll Bar : Since we are developing for a potential touch surface so scrollbars are not meant to be visible every time.

Blank Page : When you press the back button then Big page Ie third page gets stored in the forward navigation property of the history element. Additionally all the resources that were being used in the third page is disposed. So the time taken to go to second page becomes huge.

Please try havig a fourth page which will have less controls. And see if any Black background issue is occuring or not. It will give a better and clear picture.

--- Update Code for permanent visibility of scroll bar---

Please download the code for listview styling from

[Listview styles](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1192076/App55.zip)

add your code to the project

and replace all FadeOutAnimation By FadeInAnimation.

This was the quickest I could do for a solution. For a Better one you can always play with the styles.

Ohh one more thing please add

```
 Style="{StaticResource    ListViewStyle1}"
```

To your list view. please try and let me know.

Comment: 1. Can I force the scrollbar to be visible?, 2. It does not happen with small page, plus I didnt mention but only the second page has NavigationCache enabled.

Comment: Let me check i read some where yes. ill get back after checking the code. :)

Comment: I'll Edit and paste the code. this is the quickest I could get by replacing all the fadeouttheme to fadeintheme. You can try on your part and keep experimenting for different stuffs.

Comment: Alright, I believe this is the solution for the scroll bar, what about the black screen/background? how can I solve it? (this is abit more important)

Comment: I have edited my Answer you can check. As for the black background Its an issue that remotely cannot be handled. If you can please test it in a surface tablet first. Maybe memory issue . None can be sure on that. If you can please explain a bit more like the xaml and its size. ill get back to you in some time :)

Comment: I edited my post, added link to my project. about the scrollbar solution, I downloaded yours and it acts the same as mine... the scrollbar visible only when u move the mouse on the listview.

Comment: You were required to replace fadeoutanimationtheme by fadeinanimation theme. And even add a style element to your list view as i mentioned

Comment: I dont have my system currently working in a tab and your link is not opening in the tab. Ill look into it as soon as possible